How to Disable All \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection} Commands
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\small\bfseries} 

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}} % Turn off subsection DOTS and PAGE NUMBER in TOC

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section I}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{subsection I}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{subsection II}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{subsection III}
\end{document}

which produces

QUESTION: How may I disable (without deleting any commands or commenting them out) all of the subsections from appearing in the TOC? (I ask, because in an actual document with many subsections, I would like to produce one TOC all the subsections delineated; and then, another TOC in which none of the subsections appear.)
Thank you.

Possible duplicate: How to hide/show section levels in the table of contents?

But doesn't "two TOCs, one more detailed than the other" need a different answer?

Change tocdepth:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\small\bfseries} 

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}} % Turn off subsection DOTS and PAGE NUMBER in TOC

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section I}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{subsection I}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{subsection II}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{subsection III}
\end{document}

